# Play 2.3 JPA Hibernate MySQL Pooling/Connection Error

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm developing a Play 2.3 Application with JPA/Hibernate and use a Heroku/ClearDB.com MySQL Database for this but after the application connects successfully to the DB I get following error:

```
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection to jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com:3306/heroku_b7ea7b2d2972532 Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 10. Exception: null.Message:User 'badd25925bdd5f' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User 'badd25925bdd5f' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)
```

I tried almost everything I saw on other posts but nothing helped... I think it has to do with pooling...?

persistence.xml

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com:3306/heroku_b7ea7b2d2972532?reconnect=true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="badd25925bdd5f"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="XXX"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="2"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="9"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

application.conf (relevant part)

```css
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com:3306/heroku_b7ea7b2d2972532"
db.default.user="badd25925bdd5f"
db.default.password="XXX"

jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem (for Play 2.3) was to add the play-hikaricp library to the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using Hibernate, but with Ebean the connection pool by default is managed by BoneCP. Try to configure it in your `application.conf`:

```
# Max connections = partitionCount * maxConnPerPartition
db.default.partitionCount=2
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
```

or in your `persistence.xml`:

```
    <property name="bonecp.partitionCount" value="2" />
    <property name="bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are using more connections then your plan .So you can

1. Either upgrade you db plans see https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb#ignite

   **or**
2. You can try scaling down your aplication see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling

Comment: This may help to get out of this problem but doesn't answer my question. I ask to limit the connections programmatically - what usually should work...